# Formating a scalebar with Latex in the title of a Matplotlib figure

Tags: formatting, tikz-arrows, matplotlib

I have an image in matplotlib, and I want to put a scalebar in the title using Latex syntax. Using the `\vdash` and `\dashv` commands I can get the ends of the scalebar, as can been seen in the Figure, but I want the lines inbetween to look better. Preferably I would want something that looks like the flat-ended tikz arrows, where length can be chosen arbitrarely, example included as a figure.

##### Is it possible to include a tikz arrow in a matplotlib title?

##### Are there any other commands available that don't require an extra package which produce a similar character as the tikz arrow?

My code used to produce the title in my figure.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

# Setup Latex params
preamble = '\n'.join([r"\usepackage{lmodern}", r"\usepackage{tikz}"])
params = {'text.latex.preamble': preamble,
          'text.usetex': True,
          'font.size': 8,
          'font.family': 'lmodern'}
matplotlib.rcParams.update(params)

# Create figure
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2)
axes = axes.flatten()
fig.set_size_inches(3.49, 3.49)

# random data for plotting
X = [1, 8, 4, 6, 2]
Y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
titles = ["%i mm" % (i*3) for i in range(5)]

# Plot, set title, and remove axis numbering
for ax, t in zip(axes, titles):
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.scatter(X, Y)
    ax.set_title(r"$\vdash \quad 800 \mu{}m \quad \dashv$")
    # ax.set_title(r"\tikz\draw[|-](0,0)--(1,0);")

plt.show()
```

[image: Example Image]

Example for creating tikz arrows taken from https://latexdraw.com/exploring-tikz-arrows/.

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
 
\usepackage{tikz}
 
\begin{document}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [-|](0,0) -- (1,0);
    \draw [|-](0,-1) -- (1,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
 
\end{document}
```

[image: Tikz arrows]

Should be mentioned that I use the following rcParams when plotting:

```
params = {'text.latex.preamble': r"\usepackage{lmodern}",
          'text.usetex': True,
          'font.size': 8,
          'font.family': 'lmodern'}
matplotlib.rcParams.update(params)
```

Comment: You can use `'text.latex.preamble': '\n'.join([r"\usepackage{lmodern}", r"\usepackage{tikz}"])` and then just use `\tikz\draw[-|](0,0)--(1,0);` to put an arrow in your title.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately it is not working for me. Could I ask you to post a full working example? Thank you!

Comment: How do you translate your `matplotlib` graphs? Do you produce pdfs directly or pgf code or or or..?

Comment: I save it as pdf. I am generating the figures for a latex document, and pdf is the prefered choice, as far as I know. plt.savefig(figuer_name.pdf, dpi=1000, bbox_inches="tight")

Comment: Maybe it is important to mention that the figure is one of four subplots in a figure.

Comment: Well, it would be easier to provide a solution if you showed a minimal `matplotlib` code (doesn't have to be your actual data, just some pseudo data is enough).

Comment: Alright, I have updated the post with a minimal matplotlib example. The script runs, so I assume tikz is imported correctly, but the output is a blank title. I have tried with and without $$. Can you generate a figure with the tikz arrow in the title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to achieve this with the default `matplotlib` drawing engine, but if you change to the `pgf` backend this works out quite nicely (in my own works I always used the `pgf` backend; spacing is incorrect in this answer though, as I didn't want to tweak the Ti*k*Z arrow lengths):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

# Setup Latex params
preamble = '\n'.join([r"\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}",
                      r"\usepackage{lmodern}",
                      r"\usepackage{tikz}",
                      r"\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}"])
params = {'pgf.preamble': preamble,
          'font.size': 8,
          'font.family': 'serif'}
mpl.use('pgf')
mpl.rcParams.update(params)

# Create figure
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2)
axes = axes.flatten()
fig.set_size_inches(3.49, 3.49)

# random data for plotting
X = [1, 8, 4, 6, 2]
Y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
titles = ["%i mm" % (i*3) for i in range(5)]

# Plot, set title, and remove axis numbering
for ax, t in zip(axes, titles):
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.scatter(X, Y)
    # ax.set_title(r"$\vdash \quad 800 \mu{}m \quad \dashv$")
    ax.set_title(r"\tikz\draw[|-](0,0)--(1,0);"
                 r"\SI{800}{\micro\metre}"
                 r"\tikz\draw[-|](0,0)--(1,0);")

# plt.show()
plt.savefig("matplotlibthingy.pdf")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was not familiar with the `pgf` backend. 
A little bit unsatisfied with the vertical positioning (The arrows don't line up well with the text). Do you have a quick fix for that?

Comment: @MartinGardfjell look at the `baseline` key in the `pgfmanual` (or named something like that), else search "set baseline of tikzpicture" or similar on the webs.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!